# HTML Select value attribute splitting results to multiple strings

Tags: php, html

I'm using Php to load users dynamically in a `Select` dropdown.
the value attributes aren't printing what is expected.

Here's how i fetch and display

```
    $fc = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from user where user_name != '$user'");
     while ($c_row = mysqli_fetch_array($fc)) {
        $cr = $c_row['user_name'];
        $reas = '<option value='.$cr.'>'.$cr.'</option>';
    }
```

Instead of my value to be `value="Pseudo User"`, its displaying as `value="Pseudo" user=""`

Comment: Try to get property of object: ```$cr = $c_row->user_name;```

Comment: @BindasSamuel Show your HTML as to what you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While appending dynamic values you have to use single quotes or double quote before them. In your case, you have started it with a single quote

```
$reas = '<option value="'.$cr.'">'.$cr.'</option>';
```

Here one more thing I have noticed that you are not appending the previous option, which in result to display the last option only.

```
$reas .= '<option value="'.$cr.'">'.$cr.'</option>';
```

Your code should be

```
while ($c_row = mysqli_fetch_array($fc)) {
    $cr = $c_row['user_name'];
    $reas .= '<option value="'.$cr.'">'.$cr.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add quotes round the value in your code, it currently isn't enclosed and so is treating `User` from `Pseudo User` as a separate attribute

```
'<option value="'.$cr.'">'
```